# Python 2.7x generators to return indexes of "False"s in a Boolean list

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator

I'm trying to write a function to return the indexes of the 'False' values in an arbitrary list. I also would like to use generators for this.

I wrote below:

```
def cursor(booleanList):
  for element in booleanList:
    if element is False:
      yield booleanList.index(element)
```

So for example I have the list below

```
testList = [True, False, True, False]
```

And then:

```
g = cursor(testList)
```

However if I use my code, I would get:

```
> g.next()
1
> g.next()
1
> g.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Whereas I expect to get:

```
> g.next()
1
> g.next()
3
> g.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Where's the problem in the code? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you ever think you want to use `index`, especially in a loop, what you really need is probably `enumerate`.

Comment: `[ind for ind, value in enumerate(testList) if not value]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the documentation of [`.index(x)`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html), it returns the index of **the first item whose value is `x`**. This explains why your generator is always yielding `1`.

Instead, you may use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) like this:

```
def cursor(booleanList):
  for index, element in enumerate(booleanList):
    if element is False:
      yield index
```

Comment: You should use `if not element: yield index`

Comment: @user3100115 I guess this depends, maybe the author does not want `0` to be yielded.

Comment: No, elements' type in the list is `bool`.

Comment: @user3100115 Indeed, but as stated in its name, it is a "test" list. We have no clue about what really is the list, neither how it is created. So I prefer to let the author decides what suits the best its needs.

Answer (score 1):

As an extension of the previous answers you may also use a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). Admittedly this is a more tailored solution but perhaps applicable to your use case. Just out of curiosity, why do you want to use a generator if you already have the list in memory?

```
testList = [True, False, True, False]

g = (i for i in range(len(testList)) if testList[i] is False)

for i in g:
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your list with indexes `[0:True, 1:False, 2:True, 3:False]` now `booleanList.index` searches for the first `False` in the list and returns the index which of course is always 1.

You mistakengly think that `for element in booleanList:` somehow exhausting the `booleanList` but it is not.

You need to use ranged `for` instead:

```
def cursor(booleanList):
  for index in range(0, len(booleanList):
    if booleanList[index] is False:
      yield index


testList = [True, False, True, False]

g = cursor(testList)

print g.next()
print g.next()
print g.next()
```